# Using std::function/mem_fn in C++11 with member functions

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, metaprogramming, function-pointers

Long story short, is there a simple/defined way to treat function objects/lambdas and member functions in a streamlined way?

If I understand right, if I use std::mem_fn, I need to pass an object of the correct type to the function call, i.e.

```
Object o;
ftncall std::mem_fun(&Object::function);
ftncall(o);
```

Ideally, there would be some way to 'attach' `o` to that function object, perhaps as a `std::weak_ptr`, so we know if o got deleted.  For example, if there were a way to do something vaguely like this:

```
Object o;
ftncall std::mem_fn(&Object::function, o); // Or maybe std::mem_fn<Object>
ftncall();
```

Now, obviously, this doesn't exist (to my knowledge).  Is there a way to wrap std::mem_fn in such a way that I don't loose the generality (and niceness) of std::mem_fn, but can 'attach' `o`, AND still play nicely with the other function type, like std::function?  Ideally, I'd still be able to use `operator()` in the way that I do with std::function.

Currently the best solution I can think of is a class that looks like this:

```
template<class T>
class MemFunWrapper {
public:
    MemFunWrapper(T* t, std::mem_fun funct) : m_t(t), m_function(funct) {}

    std::mem_fun operator*() { return m_function; }
    T* get() { return m_t; }
private:
    T* m_t;
    std::mem_fun m_function;
}
```

Then you could use it thusly:

```
(*MemFunWrapper)(MemFunWrapper->get(), args...);
```

But that seems pretty unwieldy to me.  Also, I'd have to create an equivalent class for std::function for that to be usable in the analogous way, and that seems silly since I can already just use std::function.  Ideally, I'd also be able to use the end product without knowing if I'm calling a member function or a regular function.  I know I'm asking a lot - any direction would be helpful.  Many thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What you're looking for is std::bind instead of std::mem_fn:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

struct Object
{
  void member()
  {
    std::cout << "yay!" << std::endl;
  }
};

int main()
{
  Object o;
  auto fn = std::bind(&Object::member, o);
  fn();
}
```

FWIW: There's a [proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3702.htm) for adding an overload to std::mem_fn accepting the object for inclusion in C++14.

Comment: Why thank you - you may have just fulfilled all my hopes and dreams!

Comment: Shouldn't the line `auto fn = std::bind(&Object::member, o);` be   `auto fn = std::bind(&Object::member, &o);` , mind the second argument to `std::bind`

Comment: Depends on your intention. Both are useful in different circumstances.

Answer (score 10):

In C++11, I usually find this is easiest done with lambdas:

```
std::shared_ptr<Object> o = std::make_shared<Object>();
auto ftncall = [o](){ if (o) o->function(); }
ftncall();
```

or, with no shared lifetime:

```
Object o;
auto ftncall = [&o](){ o.function(); }
ftncall();
```

or with a weak ptr:

```
std::shared_ptr<Object> o = std::make_shared<Object>();
std::weak_ptr<Object> wo = o;
auto ftncall = [ow](){ if (auto o = wo.lock()) o->function(); }
ftncall();
```

If you need type erasure, just stuff it into a `std::function<void()>`.

Lambdas in C++11 can do much the same job as `bind` does without having to rely on library functions to do it, and I personally find them much more readable.

There are some situations where `bind` can do a better job in C++11, but they are corner cases at this point (in C++1y, more corners will be cut off as well).

Comment: Just out of curiosity, could you show me some examples `std::bind` is better in C++11? I pondered for some time but I could not find any. Is it related to the lack of polymorphic lambda?

Comment: @Sungmin `bind` supports perfect forwarding, while lambdas do not.  Lambdas cannot be polymorphic, while `bind` can.  A lambda has a fixed return type: `bind` could vary, if you pass it a functor with multiple overloads.  `bind` supports wrapping variardic functors and remaining variardic, lambdas do not.  `bind`s can be called in non-evaluated contexts, like `decltype`, useful for `auto foo()->decltype(bind(blah))`: while the type is obtuse, it isn't magic like labmda.  Those are the ones I can think of off the top of my head.  Over half of them are gone in C++1y.

Comment: Also incredibly helpful - this does seem 'easier' as you say, but it's good to know I'll still need to use `bind` if I'm going to be using polymorphic functions - probably the likeliest of situations that would cause an issue for me at least.

Comment: Another difference, I noticed (at least in MSVS) that the lambda version requires the function that's being called to be const.

Comment: @maxfeldcamp use `mutable` on lambda to relax that requirement.

Comment: **This does not work for me** (tried gcc 6.1 and gcc 11.3). Please see [this example here](https://godbolt.org/z/K9hvaG68s). Obviously, the pointer `o` is a nullptr inside the lambda braces and therefore the member function is not called.  Why is this? **Most surprisingly** , when `if (o)` is removed, the whole construct works as intended. I'm baffled.

Comment: @DanielK. I omitted the actual creation of the object in my example.  I'll add it back in.  The one that works is working due to UB.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Thank you for your prompt reply and thanks for the hints.  I figured that Undefined Behaviour is detected (at runtime) when I add `-fsanitize=undefined`.  However calling the member function on a null pointer I expected to abort the program/core dump/etc.

Comment: @DanielK. UB isn't that defined

Comment: @DanielK. Undefined behavior's behavior is not defined to abort the program/core dump/etc.  It is undefined behavior.  The behavior you get when your program does undefined behavior is not defined by the C++ standard.  This can include time travel, drawing a picture on your screen, formatting your hard drive, magically working, or a program abort.  I have seen every one of these happen, including time travel, as a result of UB in a program.  While it is funny that time travel can occur, I am actually not joking: UB can cause bugs to occur in your program before the UB runs.